# Disable Monday after 4:00pm on Saturday

Tags: php, datetime

I have built a small function that disables dates on my js calendar (which would explain the -1 month) after 4 pm the following date will be disabled. The business I built this for is opened Monday - Saturday, so a problem arises when it's Saturday it will disable Sunday but actually it needs to disable Monday (their next working day). How can I edit my code to allow Monday to be disabled if it's after 4:00PM on Saturday while retaining the other days?

**My working code:**

```
$datetime = new DateTime();

$deadline = new DateTime("today 4:00PM");

$today = new Datetime('today');

$todays = $today->format('Y-m-d');

$db_date = strtotime($todays);

$todaydisable = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 month", $db_date));

if($datetime > $deadline){
    $tomorrow = Date("Y,m,d", strtotime("+1 day -1 month "));

} else {
    $tomorrow = NULL;
}
```

**Tried the code below doesn't work either** It will disable the next day but does not disable Monday if it's after 4 on Saturday

```
            $now      = new DateTime("-1 month");
        $deadline = clone $now;
        $deadline->setTime(4, 00);
        if ($now > $deadline) {
            $now->modify('+1 day');
            $when = ('-1 month Saturday' === $now->format('l')) ? '-1 month Next Monday' : '-1 month Tomorrow';
            $tomorrow = new DateTime($when);
            $tomorrowFormat = $tomorrow->format('Y,m,d');
        } else {
            $tomorrowFormat = NULL;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$now= new DateTime();
$deadline = clone $now;
$deadline->setTime(16, 00);
if ($now > $deadline) {
    //$now->modify('+1 day');
    $when = ('Saturday' === $now->format('l')) ? '-1 Month Next Monday' : '-1 Month Tomorrow';
    $tomorrow = new DateTime($when);
}
```

Just used John Conde code, add the -1 Month, should work. Prints out 2014-01-24, so basically it should disable monday 24 feb in the jscal

Comment: I updated my code:    $now= new DateTime();
   $deadline = clone $now;
   $deadline->setTime(4, 00);
   if ($now > $deadline) {
    $now->modify('+1 day');
    $when = ('Saturday' === $now->format('l')) ? '-1 Month Next Monday' : '-1 Month Tomorrow';
    $tomorrow = new DateTime($when);
    $tomorrowFormat = $tomorrow->format('Y,m,d');
   } else {
    $tomorrowFormat = NULL;
   }. This is my var_dump: string(10) "2014,01,23" So it's returning Sunday not Monday?

Comment: @Lynx modified the code, removed the modify +1 day, should be working now, here's a working fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/nsw-q9c

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$now      = new DateTime();
$deadline = clone $now;
$deadline->setTime(16, 00);
if ($now > $deadline) {
    $now->modify('+1 day');
    $when = ('Saturday' === $now->format('l')) ? 'Next Monday' : 'Tomorrow';
    $tomorrow = new DateTime($when);
}
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8Y63Bk)

Comment: Didn't seem to work correctly. It seemed to have disabled the following months day after the current date. Before the change: http://i.imgur.com/VuRxRAB.png | After change: http://i.imgur.com/ESp5eXp.png